# filter by dates ranges in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to add a bit of SQL to my code, but not entirely sure where to add it.

**Current code:**

```
Me.List5.RowSource = "SELECT  TOP " & Nz(Me.Text9.Value, 0) & " RTI.CRN,
                              Sum(RTI.Credit) AS Credit,
                              Count(RTI.CRN) AS [Count]
                      FROM    RTI
                      GROUP BY  RTI.CRN
                      ORDER BY  Sum(RTI.Credit) DESC;"
```

I need to add a part to search between dates that are in textboxes. I think I need the following code:

```
AND [StatusDateTime] >= [Text1] AND <= [Text2]
```

Is my date code right? and where would I add it to my original SQL?

Thanks

Comment: SQL `WHERE` clause syntax should be: `AND [StatusDateTime] >= [Text1] AND [StatusDateTime] <= [Text2]`. I would consider using [DateDiff](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php) to determine witch date is earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That condition would filter the resulting set, so its place is in a `WHERE` clause, whose place is right after the `FROM`.

You can write that condition either this way

```
[StatusDateTime] >= [Text1] AND [StatusDateTime] <= [Text2]
```

or this (more compact) way

```
[StatusDateTime] between [Text1] and [Text2]
```

The resulting query would then be

```
Me.List5.RowSource = "SELECT TOP " & Nz(Me.Text9.Value, 0) & " RTI.CRN,
                             Sum(RTI.Credit) AS Credit,
                             Count(RTI.CRN) AS [Count]
                      FROM   RTI
                      WHERE  [StatusDateTime] between [Text1] and [Text2]
                      GROUP BY  RTI.CRN
                      ORDER BY Sum(RTI.Credit) DESC;"
```

Comment: I decided to go with this: [StatusDateTime] between [Text1] and [Text2]    I have previously been told that using between is not accurate all them time compared to using >= and <=. I take it that's not the case?

Comment: Never heard anything about `between` not being accurate, I'm pretty sure the dbms translates it into `>=` and `<=`, it's just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

Comment: @StefanoZanini, please see [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: @HoneyBadger interesting reading, thanks! Seems to me though that the biggest issue is the wrong assumptions one may do on the `between` behavior (mostly when using constant date values), but once it's clear what it will do, its accuracy in doing that is not in doubt... am I right?

Comment: @StefanoZanini, That's right, there's nothing inherently wrong with `between`, but personally I think `>= ..<=` is more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should add it after "FROM RTI"

2) It should be like

```
AND [StatusDateTime] >= [Text1] AND [StatusDateTime] <= [Text2]
```

Or

```
AND [StatusDateTime] BETWEEN [Text1] AND [Text2]
```